# First row calculation is zero in crystal report grouping

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have added a formula in crystal reports to calculate a value. The report also uses the grouping logic. The calculation for first group alone is displayed as Zero, but actually has values are in database. from second group it calculates perfectly.

The formula runs as,

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numberVar Total20PercentAmount;
numberVar TotalAmount;

if {Table1.TypeCode} in [11, 13, 14, 15, 17]  then
(
    Total20PercentAmount:=Total20PercentAmount+{Table1.Amount}*20/100;
);

TotalAmount:=TotalAmount+Total20PercentAmount+{Table1.Amount};
```

The result is,

```
group1   0      0
group2   245   1459
group3   563   1478
group4   985   5085
```

But the both values are dispalyed as zero only for the first group.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the formula field which was placed after the group details section. After moving up ahead to the group section, it worked

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Whileprintingrecords` and check the result.

Comment: The issue was with the formula field which was placed after the group details section. After moving ahead to the group section, it worked.